# Binary signal probability

Tags: probability

You are doing an experiment to observe a binary signal. You can't view the signal directly, but through two instruments. The instruments have error rates a and b, respectively. The error rates are independent. What is the probability they are:
a) both correct? 
b) give matching signals? 
c) give matching, but incorrect signals?

I drew a tree diagram starting with 2 instruments, branching into whether they flashed on or off, and each branch further separated into whether that was in error or not.

I have for

a) $(1/2)*(1-a)*(1-b)+(1/2)*(1-a)*(1-b)$

b) $(1/2)(1/2) + (1/2)(1/2)$

c) $(1/2)a*(1/2)b + (1/2)a*(1/2)b$

Can someone let me know if this is correct? If not, please explain why.

Comment: I get $(1-a)(1-b)+ab$ for b). Note that you should have $P(B) = P(A)+P(C)$, where $A,B,C$ refer to the events a), b), c).

Comment: I assume that this is a one-bit signal so that if they are both incorrect they must also match - otherwise there is not enough information to determine b) or c).

Comment: Intuition for second case, assume  error rates are both zero and both one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_{1}=1-a$ and $q_{1}=a$ be the probability for instrument 1 to measure respectively correct and incorrect signal. Similary, let $p_{2}=1-b$ and $q_{2}=b$ be the probability for instrument 2 to measure respectively correct and incorrect signal.

(a) The probability that both instruments measure correct signals

$P=p_{1}*p_{2}=(1-a)(1-b)$

(c) The probability that both instruments measure incorrect signals

$Q=q_{1}*q_{2}=ab$

(b) Use the same logic as @copper.hat to get $(1-a)(1-b)+ab$

Answer (score 0):

Say your devices are called $A$ and $B$ and the signal source is called $S$.  The signal $S$ is on with probability $p$.  Device $A$ flips the signal it receives with probability $a$ and device $B$ flips the signal it receives with probability $b$.

a)  Assuming $p = P\{S_{on}\} = 1/2$ then your answer, after simplifying, is just $(1-a)(1-b)$ which I believe is correct.

b)  For this question we want to know the unconditional probability that both devices will emit the same signal.  A detailed derivation follows:

\begin{align}
& P\{Both \ signals \ are \ the \ same\} \\
& = P\{A_{on} \cap B_{on}\} + P\{A_{off} \cap B_{off}\} \\
& = P\{A_{on} \cap B_{on} \cap S_{on} \} +P\{A_{on} \cap B_{on} \cap S_{off} \} \\ 
& \ \ \ \ \  + P\{A_{off}\cap B_{off}\cap S_{on}\} +P\{A_{off}\cap B_{off}\cap S_{off}\} \\
& = P\{A_{on}\cap B_{on}|S_{on}\}P\{S_{on}\} + P\{A_{on}\cap B_{on}|S_{off}\}P\{S_{off}\} \\
& \ \ \ \ \ + P\{A_{off}\cap B_{off}|S_{on}\}P\{S_{on}\} + P\{A_{off}\cap B_{off}|S_{off}\}P\{S_{off}\} \\
& = (1-a)(1-b)p + ab(1-p) + abp + (1-a)(1-b)(1-p) \\
& = (1-a)(1-b) + ab \\
\end{align}

c) Since as @copper.hat points out, the result for question b) should be the sum of the results for questions a) and c).  Thus, by subtraction it must be that the result for the case where both $A$ and $B$ are wrong is just $ab$.  For a more direct proof use an approach similar to what I used above to perhaps see why your answer is different.